# Initiate Lync Conversation with specific subject

Tags: lync-2013, ucma, ucwa, lync-server-2013

currently i involve in web based document management project. There's a requirement to retrieve the Lync IM conversation history that is related with any specific document.

so the team is decided to use conversation subject as the key to filter the IM conversation history. in big picture, if user A want to chat user B about document C, then user A should click a button in web app, then web app will launch the Lync conversation between them and set the conversation subject with "Document C's ID".

now the problem is, how to launch the Lync conversation with subject from the web app? i have tried the Lync SDK with no luck. there's an error "Microsoft.Lync.Model.ClientNotFoundException: The host process is not running" when the codes run in web app. its running well while its running in desktop app. i have done some research about UCWA, unfortunately there are some prerequisites need to be configured in Lync Server to activate the UCWA. so i can't try the sample codes that is available on http://ucwa.skype.com in our production server. i just want to ensure this can be done by UCWA before i setup my development servers (AD, Exchange, Lync etc) since it take a lot of efforts to setup the whole things.

FYI, we use Lync 2013 client, exchange 2013, Lync server 2013 for this case.

Comment: have you figured this out

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "error when running from the webapp"? The C# code runs on the server, so thats expected.

Can you use a protocol handler in the website? IE: <a href="lynchelper://id of document"/> and then register the protocol on the clients? Let the protocol start up your helper and let that use the Lync client SDK. Problem with this apporach is, you need access to all the clients and if the protocol is unregistered a big error is shown.

If not possible you could write an UCMA application which starts up the conversation to both parties.

Comment: From my own limited experience I believe the error "The host process is not found" means that the Lync client is not running. I don't think using the client side SDK on the server side will get you the results you want; I would recommend seeking out server side options.

Comment: @GrahamMc, That's exactly what i mean, but a different solution: From the OP i figured maybe he is calling LyncClient.GetClient() in code behind. Thus running the client SDK code really on the server instead of workstation where Lync /SfB runs. I think Silverlight will enable clicking a webcontrol and transferring it to the local client, but i have no experience with that. However, a protocolhandler with client application will work definitively. (Although Im not sure it is a fit for the problem and Idam doesn't seem to react)